# How to find information about a function?

Tags: functions, help

To be able to learn about functions on my own I would like to know where I can find information about them (within emacs or otherwise).

Comment: What have you tried?  What was unsatisfactory about what you found when you tried?

Answer (score 1):

In addition to `C-h f` which gives you information about functions as you found out, the `C-h` prefix key leads to all sorts of other documentation as well: variables, keys, log messages, modes, the Info manuals and much more - type `C-h ?` to get the list.

Answer (score 0):

`C-h f` lets you find information about functions. It will prompt you for the name of the function which you want to read about. Upon entering a valid function name, it will open the documentation in a split window.

Comment: Good answer. But it would help if you gave a little more info about `C-h f`.

Answer (score 0):

C-h f  (describe-function ) displays the complete documentation for  and allows you to access the elisp source code. You can activate the step-by-step execution mode of this function by C-u C-M -x - see (info "'(elisp) Using Edebug") - and thus examine its dynamic operation. This is a very good way to understand how the elisp code for this function works.

Comment: `C-h f`, you mean.